# Error importing mgo driver

Tags: go, mgo

I'm trying to use the mgo driver. I run

```
go get gopkg.in/mgo.v2
```

To get the package, but get these errors -

```
# gopkg.in/mgo.v2/internal/scram
/usr/local/go/src/pkg/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/internal/scram/scram.go:86: c.out.Grow undefined (type bytes.Buffer has no field or method Grow)
/usr/local/go/src/pkg/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/internal/scram/scram.go:87: c.authMsg.Grow undefined (type bytes.Buffer has no field or method Grow)
# gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson
/usr/local/go/src/pkg/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson/decode.go:246: k.Convert undefined (type reflect.Value has no field or method Convert)
/usr/local/go/src/pkg/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson/encode.go:56: undefined: json.Number
/usr/local/go/src/pkg/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson/encode.go:282: undefined: json.Number
```

Should I be doing something else?

Answer (score 1):

Update Go to the latest version by going to https://golang.org/dl/. In case you worry about uninstallation of Go, all you need to do is delete the Go folder, that's it. This will most probably solve the problem. But if the problem persists, then send me the screenshot of the errors.